# Adding data to datagridview without losing existing rows

Tags: c#

hello every body i am new to c# and now im trying to add rows to datagridview using query and invoke but the problem is whenever i try to insert data to table in rewrites all rows so just one row that has the last verified value shown in the rows. i have tried so many thing but i dont know where the problem is. this is my code:

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("demo.xml");
         var query = from key in xdoc.Descendants("user")
                     where key != null && (key.Element("clientno").Value == recieveddata)
                     select new
                     {
                         //listBox3.Items.Add(key.Element("name")+""+key.Element("lastname"));
                         نام = key.Element("name").Value +" "+ key.Element("lastname").Value,
                        // خانوادگی = key.Element("lastname").Value,
                       ورزش = key.Element("noeozviat").Value,
                        تاریخ = key.Element("date").Value,
                         عضویت = key.Element("duration").Value,
                        جلسات = key.Element("jalasat").Value
                     };dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList()));
```

please help me on this.

Comment: I would recommend to never user something like "تاریخ " in code! By using standard characters everyone can read your code.

Comment: thank you for advice but it is not the problem the problem is that every time the query get just one data but i want to add this data to another row not the row that existed before.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list and setting it as the data source every time.  What you should be doing is creating a class for each element (at the moment you are using an anonymous type), then ADD new elements when you run the query and set this list as the new data source.

Something like this:

```
class Thing
{ 
   public string نام {get;set;}
   // Etc
}

List<Thing> items = new List<Thing>(); // <- should be a class member variable, not a local variable

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("demo.xml");
var newItems = from key in xdoc.Descendants("user")
                 where key != null && (key.Element("clientno").Value == recieveddata)
                 select new Thing
                 {
                     نام = key.Element("name").Value +" "+ key.Element("lastname").Value,
                   ورزش = key.Element("noeozviat").Value,
                    تاریخ = key.Element("date").Value,
                     عضویت = key.Element("duration").Value,
                    جلسات = key.Element("jalasat").Value
                 };
items.AddRange(newItems.ToList());
dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.DataSource = items));
```

Comment: thanks can you explain more i did exactly like you said but nothing is shown in datagridview

Comment: How many items are in `items` when you step through the code?  Also, you will have to change your datagrid to extract the correct properties of the items.

Comment: getting error while using `items.AddRange(newItems.ToList());` this is error i get `Error 26 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GymAttendaceSystem.Thing>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GymAttendaceSystem.Thing>)' has some invalid arguments c:\users\hamed\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\gymattendacesystem\gymattendacesystem\form1.cs 176 14 GymAttendaceSystem
`

Comment: What type is `newItems`?

Comment: i made the error fixed but the problem is the same as it was whenever i want to add new data to datagridview it removes the data that were before in the rows and adds new row with one single row that is returned from query